# Flat tables enabled from admin but it does not init flat tables

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1

The problem is that when Magento tries to load the search results by some ids, it does not take the same number of products as it should be. I debugged and saw that despite the fact that we're using flat tables, Magento's query is build on EAV tables.

I verified that in Sustem->Configuration->Catalog->Frontend to specified Magento to use flat tables but it does not work.

Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->isEnabled() returns false and because of this, the flat tables are not used. I guess?

Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->isEnabled() returns true, so I guess flat is enabled after all.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you make reindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the collection in the admin area, flat tables are never used.

It also can be that the flat tables are not used while the indexer is running. Check the indexer status in the index management.